# Proper way to log in an ASP.NET Website running in Azure

Tags: asp.net, azure, logging, azure-storage, azure-web-app-service

I've read several articles about logging in an Azure Website but I cannot make my final decision. My big question is to use or not to use a 3rd party library for logging.
I see that the built in diagnostics functionality is quite good. I could use it to create debug logs like "Xyz with ID [x] was created by User [abc]..." and store these along with trace messages in an Azure table storage, but I'm not sure that this will serve me long enough. On the other hand, I think that using both the built in tracing and NLog for example, is a little overkill.

Any experiences/suggestions on this topic?

Answer (score 2):

You can use NLog or similar library and add a sink that writes to System.Diagnostics.Trace.

This way you can enjoy both worlds, on one hand it's easy to direct these logs to file/blob/table where you can change log level on the fly from the portal (it will not restart your website) and on the other you can enjoy the benefits of those third party libraries.

Answer (score 1):

Azure Application Insights is another great way to do logging in Azure Websites. See [here](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Azure-Friday/Instrumenting-your-Web-API-using-Application-Insights-with-Victor-Mushkatin).

There is also [ELMAH](https://code.google.com/p/elmah/) that you can nuget into your site.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but for me, Azure Application Insights seems like a NewRelic competitor. It is not primarily for logging and my question relates to that.

Comment: @laszlokiss88 - you can log to application insights... It does a lot of different things, including logging.. but no, it's not its primary purpose.  You can even use sinks to application insights from various logging frameworks like serilog.

Answer (score 0):

Choosing the right logging approach depends a lot on what exactly you want from your logging. For ASP.NET, it always helps if the log is "REQUEST BASED" rather than just a plain TEXT file which contains all the events. There are many different logging frameworks available but I want to highlight one which is an "out of box" feature and works really well if you want to measure performance of a request and if you want your tracing to be request based. I am basically talking about the old Trace.Write in ASP.NET. With the following configuration in your web.config, your ASP.NET trace events will be logged in to FREB whenever FREB tracing is enabled.

```
<system.web>
  <trace enabled="true" pageOutput="false" requestLimit="10000" writeToDiagnosticsTrace="true" />
</system.web>
<system.diagnostics>
  <sharedListeners>
    <add name="System.Net.IISETW" type="System.Web.IisTraceListener,System.Web,version=4.0.0.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
  </sharedListeners>
  <trace autoflush="true" />
</system.diagnostics>
```

This way when you enable failed request tracing as mentioned [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/benjaminperkins/archive/2013/08/01/enabling-failed-request-logging-on-a-windows-azure-web-site.aspx), your custom events will start showing up in the FREB traces and you can see how much time is spent in between each event and this gives you a good way of identify how much time is spent in your request execution.

hope this helps !!!